# If $x = lim (x_n)$ and if $|x_n - c| < \epsilon~~ \forall ~n \in N$, then it is true that $|x-c|< \epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

If $x = lim (x_n)$ and if $|x_n - c| < \epsilon~~ \forall ~n \in N$, then is it true that $|x-c|< \epsilon?$

I am a little confused about this question ( it appears in the Bartle's elements of real analysis  )

> There is no mention of $\epsilon$ and what it satisfies. But going by the usual definition, is it safe to presume that the question means the following? :
>
> If $x = \lim (x_n)$ and if $~~\forall ~\epsilon >0~, ~ |x_n - c| < \epsilon~~ \forall ~n \in N$, then it is true that $|x-c|< \epsilon?$

If this is what the question is asking about, then $x_n$ should be a single point sequence only $c$ should be the limit point and be the same as $x$ which of course should satisfy $|x-c|< \epsilon$?

Am I correct on my assumption?

Thank you for your help?

Comment: The rule of thumb is that if you have an inequality which is true for all but finitely many $n$, then its nonstrict version also holds in the limit. This nonstrictness requirement is important: for example, we can have $x_n = 1-1/n$ and $c=0$, then $|x_n|<1$ but $|x|=1$.

Comment: That means my assumption and inference is correct?

Comment: They don't mean $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary, they are fixing a particular $\varepsilon$. So $c$ need not be the limit. For example, in my situation we have $|x_n-0|<1$ for all $n$, and when we take the limit, since the absolute value is continuous we end up with $|x-0| \leq 1$.

Comment: Are you sure the book says $|x - c| < \varepsilon$ and not $|x - c| \leq \varepsilon$? Or does it perhaps say "Is it true?" rather than "It is true"?

Comment: @Dave Yes, I am sure about the inequality. And I am sorry, the problem actually reads "Is it True?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't assume that $\forall \varepsilon > 0 \ |x_n - c| < \varepsilon$.

The correct interpretation is:

Is it true that $\forall \text{ sequence } \{x_n \} \ \forall x \ \forall c \ \forall \varepsilon > 0 \ [(\lim_n x_n = x \text{ and } \forall n \ |x_n - c|< \varepsilon) \Longrightarrow |x - c| < \varepsilon ]$?

The answer is no, as others have explained.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)